# File created using ofstream is empty after reboot

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing a function using `ofstream` to update a config file in `/etc/dns.conf`. BUT my file is EMPTY after system REBOOT (file is there but no contents).

I thought flush() will synchronize the contents to the physical file immediately.But something is wrong in my implementation. Please help me to find the real problem here.

Basically I create a tmp file `/etc/dns.bak` with the required data, then remove the original file `/etc/dns.conf` and rename the tmp file to `/etc/dns.conf` (Note that program is run as root so all file permissions are there).

Steps followed:

- Add the required data to a vector
- Open a tmp file using `ofstream` with .bak extension
- Iterate through vector and write the data to the file using `<<` operator
- Flush the file using `flush()`
- Close the file using `close()`
- Remove the original file using `std::remove`
- Rename the tmp file to original file using `std::rename`
- cat the file (It outputs the correct content / Also I can see the file with correct sizes on the physical disk)
- Reboot the system after 15 seconds
- /etc/dns.conf is found it's empty (nothing has persisted over reboot)

Since my code base has much more logic, I created a code segment exactly what I'm doing with the files

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> m_dnsData_;

// I'm running as root and /etc/dns.conf exists
std::string m_dnsPath_ = std::string("/etc/dns.conf");
std::string m_dnsBackup_ = std::string("/etc/dns.bak");

bool ReplaceFile() {
        // Open the file in the backup path
        std::ofstream dns_backup;
        dns_backup.open(m_dnsBackup_.c_str());//default is ios::out

        // add data to the file
        for (auto& i : m_dnsData_) {
                dns_backup << (i + std::string("\n"));
        }

        dns_backup.flush(); // to synchronize the data with the physical file
        dns_backup.close(); // close the file

        // remove the original
        int rc = std::remove(m_dnsPath_.c_str());
        if (rc) {
                std::cout << "Error remove [DNS]..." << std::endl;
                return false;
        }

        rc = std::rename(m_dnsBackup_.c_str(), m_dnsPath_.c_str());
        if (rc) {
                std::cout << "Error renaming [DNS]..." << std::endl;
                return false;
        }
}

int main() {
        // vector is filled with the required configurations
        m_dnsData_.push_back(std::string("some config 1"));
        m_dnsData_.push_back(std::string("some config 2"));

        if (ReplaceFile() == true) {
                std::cout << "File created successfully!" << std::endl;
        } else {
                std::cout << "File creation failed!" << std::endl;
        }

        // I can see the correct contents here
        system((std::string("cat ") + m_dnsPath_).c_str());

        // Also can see the file has correct size and correct data
        // using vi /etc/dns.conf

        // Reboot the system after 15 seconds

        // After reboot the file can be seen
        // But "/etc/dns.conf" has no contents

        return 0;
}
```

> **I Found a Solution**
>
> Added sync() method before reboot (you need `unistd.h`). 
>   Then the file persisted upon reboot.

Comment: I never heard of a file named `dns.conf`, but another file named `resolv.conf` that also handles resolving of names is automatically overwritten on Linux systems on reboot. Could that be the case here?

Comment: This is a custom config file used in my project. It can be any name.

Comment: Flush does what it can, but the OS likely buffers writes and the disk may buffer as well.

Comment: How do you reboot? Do you shutdown the system before, so all buffers are written to disk?

Comment: execute reboot command using system(). @user4581301 how do I ensure everything is in sync before issuing the reboot command? use sync()?

Comment: `sync` will get it to the disk, but you may still need time for the disk to permanently store.

Comment: @SajithP No. These comments are misleading. If you close your files, which you do, any buffers on your end will be automatically flushed to kernel/hardware land. If you then reboot with the `reboot` command, anything else remaining will be properly sync'd, written, and dealt with. None of that is your problem here. Everything about your program is correct. Something else is overwriting your file.

Comment: Try the following to narrow this down: 1. Change your files to `~/dns.conf`and `~/dns.bak`, run the test, reboot, check file contents. 2. Edit `/etc/dns.conf` manually with a text editor, reboot, check its contents. 3. Use another file in /etc, like `/etc/test.conf` and `/etc/test.bak`. Run your program. Reboot. 4. Check the timestamp on `/etc/dns.conf` after running your program. Reboot. Check the file timestamp again. See if they are different. Please report back these four results.

Comment: Also, are you running dnsmasq? Some configurations seem to use /etc/dns.conf rather than /etc/resolv.conf and `resolvconf` *does* rewrite this file on boot. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot for example. My guess is you are conflicting with this and attempting to manually overwrite an automatically generated file.

Comment: I don't know why this is put on hold as this program recreates the problem on my CentOS machine at office. Cannot recreate on a Mac though. @JasonC I will share results soon. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: @JasonC I found that calling sync() before rebooting resolves the problem. The CentOS version that I'm running doesn't have a network manager so it not alteration is done to the dns configs in /etc during bootup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of you for your valuable input!

Comment: @SajithP That's super weird, but I'm glad you solved it! What is the underlying storage? An HD? An SSD? An SD card? Some other kind of flash?